# What does typename mean in this context

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I'm reading [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) so I'm now looking at the implementation of `std::forward` and `std::move`:

```
    // TEMPLATE FUNCTION forward
template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty&& forward(typename identity<_Ty>::type& _Arg)
    {   // forward _Arg, given explicitly specified type parameter
    return ((_Ty&&)_Arg);
    }

    // TEMPLATE FUNCTION move
template<class _Ty> inline
    typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&
        move(_Ty&& _Arg)
    {   // forward _Arg as movable
    return ((typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&)_Arg);
    }
```

I think I get the whole story but I don't understand the use of the `typename` outside of the template definition (`template<...>`). What does it mean in this case?

Comment: It's to let the compiler know to interpret the next token as a type rather than a variable name.

Comment: @Nawaz: thanks for that link, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It indicates that `identity<_Ty>::type&` is a *type*, not a *static variable* from the class.

Here's a simpler example:

```
template<class T> void f() { T::x * p; ... }
```

You can think that `p` is a pointer to something of a class `T::x`. 
Or you can think that `T::x` is a static variable that gets multiplied by `p`. 
So, in this case the compiler can't really know what did you mean by this code.

To avoid such ambiguousness, you should specify that `T::x` is a type by adding `typename`:

```
template<class T> void f() { typename T::x * p; ... }
```

It's kind of the same thing in your case.

Comment: Well that seems obvious, can it be removed?